# androidx worker manager issue - " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse result path string: "

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-workmanager

I tried to implement

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.0.1"
```

today. It downloaded (initial build) fine but when I try to rebuild project or to run on my device I am facing a really weird issue.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse result path string:

Now I tried different version of Worker Manager even without ktx , try to clean the project, ran gradle with --scan option to know the issue, invalidated caches/restart but everything in vain.

project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    ext.version_code = 13
    ext.version_name = "2.0.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dawnimpulse.wallup"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode version_code
        versionName version_name
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //--------------- Support Libraries ---------------------
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"

    //--------------- Firebase Libraries --------------------

    //--------------- 3rd Party Libraries -------------------
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' // image loading
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0' // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1' //rx android
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.1.0' //rx relay
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding-recyclerview:3.0.0-alpha2' //rx recycler
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0' //rounding images
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0' // photo view
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:3.0.0' //blur library

    //------------------ Additional -------------------------
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: run this command from command line 'gradlew  --debug assembleDebug' and share the log.

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't worked. Although I have fixed this issue by moving to Android Gradle plugin version 3.4.0 . There was some issue with 3.4.1 & I have submitted the bug report to android. Thanks for the help